# Tibco 7.14 connectivity issues with Hive EMR (AWS) using JDBC driver

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, hive, tibco

Unable to view the table contents in Tibco Spotfire Analytics Explorer.

I have copied the hive EMR jar files to library folder in tibco server. Once the server is up, I tried to configure the data source in Information Designer. I am able to setup the datasource and I can see schema. But when I tried to expand the table, I am not getting any results

This is the error message I am getting here

```
Error message: An issue occurred while creating the default model. It may be partially constructed.
The data source reported a failure.

InformationModelException at Spotfire.Dxp.Data:
Error retrieving metadata: java.lang.NullPointerException (HRESULT: 80131500)
```

The following is the URL template in Information Designer
`jdbc:hive2://<host>:<port10000>/<database>`

which I changed to 
`jdbc:hive2://sitename:10000/db_name`.

Please let me know what need to be changed in the driver config or any other place to see the contents of the table.